# update list of colors in update controller laravel

Tags: laravel, sql-update

I have for each of value from color of my product. Any product can gives to many color
this color save it in interface table with for each .
my store for each

```
foreach ($request->addcolor as $colorss) {
        foreach ($colorss as $item){
            if(!empty($item['color_id'])){
                $color = ColorProduct::create([
                    'product_id' => $product->id,
                    'color_id' => $item['color_id'],
                    'color_body'=>$request->input('color_body'),
                    'color_handle' => $request->input('color_handle'),
                    'color_handle_head' => $request->input('color_handle_head'),
                    'productable' => Product::class
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
```

I wrote update this for each

```
    if($request->addcolor ){

        $color_product = ColorProduct::where('product_id' , $product->id)->get();
        foreach ($request->addcolor as $keys => $colorsis) {
            $color = $color_product->where('color_id' , $keys)->first();
            if ($color) {
                foreach ($request->addcolor as $colorss) {
                    foreach ($colorss as $item){
                        if(!empty($item['color_id'])){
                            $item['color_id'] = $request->input ('color_id');
                            $item['color_body']= $request->input('color_body');
                            $item['color_handle'] = $request->input('color_handle');
                            $item['color_handle_head'] =  $request->input('color_handle_head');
                        }

                    }
                }
            } else {
                foreach ($colorss as $procol){
                    if(!empty($procol['color_id'])){
                        $color = ColorProduct::create([
                            'product_id' => $product->id,
                            'color_id' => $procol['color_id'],
                            'productable' => Product::class
                        ]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $duplicateArgs= DB::table('color_products')
            ->select('product_id' , 'color_id' , DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
            ->groupBy('product_id' , 'color_id')
            ->get();
        foreach ($duplicateArgs as $item){
            if($item->total>1){
                for ($i = 1; $i < $item->total; $i++){
                    $duplicate = ColorProduct::where('product_id' , $item->product_id)
                        ->where('color_id' , $item->color_id)->orderBy('id' , 'Desc')->first();
                    $duplicate->delete();
                }
            }
        }
```

how can update color body, color handle, color handle head ?I can only update color id

thanks for your help

Comment: where is there any update happening at all?

Answer (score 0):

I am a little unclear of the data structure here, but maybe you need to do something like this in your first foreach?

```
$color->update([
    'color_id' = $request->input ('color_id'),
    'color_body' = $request->input('color_body'),
    'color_handle' = $request->input('color_handle'),
    'color_handle_head' =  $request->input('color_handle_head')
]);
```